# Question regarding Oauth and https

Tags: tls

Whats the difference between Oauth protocol and https protocol?

Comment: By the way, see those Wiki pages i linked in my awnser? thats the *first result* you get when typing in HTTPS or OAuth in google, try doing a bit of reshearch of your own before asking questions! :)

Comment: Is it possible for https protocol and Oauth protocol to run at the same time for an application?

Comment: Well ofcourse! HTTPS is a CONNECTION and OAuth a FRAMEWORK, which have nothing to do with each other, heck, when using a login feature/secured files, you always need to use HTTPS!

Comment: Okay so HTTPS is establishing a connection between the client and the server. OAuth acts as a gatemaster to this https connection. Am i right to say that?

Comment: yup, totally right

Comment: Hi i want to ask one more question, can oauth2.0 run on http? or https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure) is a way of securing a connection using SSL/TLS encryption, so that people have a harder time/aren't able to eavesdrop on you.

[OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) (Open Authorization) is an Open Source authentication framework that utilizes tokens for a secure login, giving limited/permission based web page access to users.

In conclusion, HTTPS is a way of securing a connection, OAuth is a way of securing Webpages with a login.